# Accessing a file in the root folder of a website in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I would like to access a specific file in the root folder of my web application in production, (RoR based), but i get the following message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /risingbacklinks/index.html on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at www.xxxxx.com Port 443
```

how do i configure my webserver to allow access to this specific file in the root.

Comment: wild guess: set full permission to your file
chmod -R 777 <dirname>

Comment: What url are you accessing? This file should be in `public` dir to be accessible.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. Problem solved, chmod -R 777. This makes me look stupid